# What story has Joan of Arc rescued by time travelers?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, short-stories

Seeing a book in the library reminded me about this short story that I read many years ago. I do not know when it was published, but I can remember a lot of other details about it. It seems like it should be pretty obvious if anyone knows it because it is a unique story.

So in this story Joan of Arc is rescued by time travelers and replaced with a duplicate, then becomes some kind of time-traveling cyborg that gets sent to various time periods to fix problems, kind of like that old show Quantum Leap. It's told from her perspective in first person.

I hope someone can help me, it's been driving me crazy that I can't recall where I read this. Thanks!

Comment: how many roughly is "many many", 1960s 70s etc?

Comment: Oh wow, this sounds epic. Kinda like Bill and Ted meets terminator....

Comment: The things that spring to mind are Bill and Ted, of course, and Mary Gentle's *Ash*, whose protagonist is a very Joan-of-Arc-like character. Neither involve cyborgs, though, and neither is a short story.

Comment: I remember seeing an independant comic book like this in the early 90's... couldnt tell you the title it was a great idea but poorly executed.

Comment: from [tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimeTravelEscape): Time-travel roleplaying game Continuum has rules for doing this (in cases where the body is proven to be that of the character) involving the character knowing that they are going to die in just that situation. Joan of Arc, for instance, is a canon NPC who was nonetheless burned at the stake. This didn't stop her from spending a few centuries as a Continuum city's entire police force.

Answer (score 4):

[A Circle of Arcs](http://www.double-dragon-ebooks.com/single.php?ISBN=1-89484-104-2) seems likely. check the prolog/first chapter on this page, and see if it rings any bells

Comment: Thanks Sean, that looks like it's the one!